# How can I send a JSON string from a java dynamic project to a google apps script?

Tags: java, google-apps

I've got a java dynamic web project and I want to send a JSON string from it to a google apps script and receive it there. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Please read our [ask] page for help on how to improve this question.  Great questions tend to get great, fast answers

Comment: Since Java is Turing-complete, I am quite confident there is a way to do what you want...

Comment: If it exists I can't find or discover how to do it, excuse my expression but I'm literally hitting my head in the table